# implement a search functionality that query MongoDB database and return all the objects which contain a user given value in node js and express

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express

I want to implement a search functionality that would query my MongoDB database and return all the objects which contain (full/partially) the name I am searching for.

**Example:
My object collection is products, and I want to see every product which contains the name I search, from the product names.**

My 'Products' collection looks like this...

```
[ { _id: 5f79,
    productName: 'Test-image12345',
    price: 60,
    details: 'Test product' },
  { _id: 5f7d,
    productName: 'Test-image1234',
    price: 60,
    details: 'Test product'},
  { _id: 5fv4,
    productName: 'Test',
    price: 60,
    details: 'Test product'},
 ]
```

Now I need to find all the products with "Test-image1234"

Answer (score 2):

```
// search a product by name
productRoute.get('/getproduct/:name', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const findname = req.params.name;
        const objs = await Product.find({productName:{ $regex:'.*'+findname+'.*'} });
        res.json(objs);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({message: error});        
    }
})
```

Now I get the answer as follows...

```
[ { _id: 5f79,
    productName: 'Test-image12345',
    price: 60,
    details: 'Test product' },
  { _id: 5f7d,
    productName: 'Test-image1234',
    price: 60,
    details: 'Test product'}
]
```